# How to implement spinner or progress bar?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I have a form data that passes file to IFormFile  to read the data in an excel file. I want to add some spinner while my method read's and uploads the data to my database. I'm passing the file from button submit... Saw some post that it can be done using Ajax, for reason I'm not sure how to implement in my code, tried some several methods using Ajax however having issue with the formdata.

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" asp-controller="UploadController" asp-action="Upload">
        <div class="mt-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6 mb-3">
                    <h3>2. Upload a File</h3>
                    <div class="custom-file">
                        <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="file" />
                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>
                        <i>Only Excel file .xls, .xlsx</i>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="mt-5">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-6">
                    <div class="float-left">
                        <button type="submit" id="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-info">Upload</button>
                        <button asp-controller="Exposure" asp-action="Index" type="submit" class="btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal">Back to List</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </form>

<---Method---->
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IFormFile file)
{
   if(file != null)
   {
   
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I change your code and add a progress bar by javascript, you can refer to the following demo:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" asp-controller="UploadController" asp-action="Upload">
    <div class="mt-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6 mb-3">
                <h3>2. Upload a File</h3>
                <div class="custom-file">
                    <input type="file" class="custom-file-input" name="file" id="File" />
                    <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile" >Choose file</label>
                    <i>Only Excel file .xls, .xlsx</i>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="mt-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <div class="float-left">
                    <button id="submit" name="Submit" class="btn btn-info" onclick="UploadImage()">Upload</button>
                    <button asp-controller="Exposure" asp-action="Index" type="submit" class="btn btn-light" data-dismiss="modal">Back to List</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>

<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success progress-bar-striped 
    active" role="progressbar"
         aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:0%">0%</div>
</div>

<script>
   function UploadImage(){
       var data = new FormData;
       var fileInput = document.getElementById("File");
       var files = fileInput.files;
      for(var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        data.append("files",files[i])
      }
      
      $.ajax({
        xhr: function() {
        var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
      
        xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt) {
          if (evt.lengthComputable) {
            var percentComplete = evt.loaded / evt.total;
            percentComplete = parseInt(percentComplete * 100);
      
            $('.progress-bar').width(percentComplete+'%');
            $('.progress-bar').html(percentComplete+'%');
      
           }
        }, false);
      
         return xhr;
        },
        url: '/UploadController/Upload',
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        success: function(result) {
          console.log(result);
        }
      });
   }
</script>
```

**Controller**

```
   [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload(IList<IFormFile> files)
    {
        //......
    }
```

**Then when you upload a file, There will be a progress bar.**

[image]